# PHP session timeout is 0, But users logged out when browser is idle for sometime

Tags: php, session, browser, authentication, logout

I have set the maxlifetime for sessions to be 0 in php.ini, so; as I understand it will be available until I close the browser.

But it doesn't, as when I leave the browser idle for sometime, and I get back to work on the app, I get to login page, which means that the session is destroyed !!

Any suggestions ?!

Answer (score 1):

There is another lifetime setting which specifies after which time the server may remove the session to avoid to many stale sessions hogging the server's resources.

Quoting from [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime):

> `session.gc_maxlifetime` specifies the number of seconds after which data will be seen as 'garbage' and potentially cleaned up. Garbage collection may occur during session start (depending on `session.gc_probability` and `session.gc_divisor`).